# How to add a Reference to the Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer namespace in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 PRO

Tags: .net, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Windows 10 Pro, Visual Studio 2019, .Net version 4.8.03752 (Clean installation of everything a few days ago).

I'm trying to add the Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer namespace to my C# project in Visual Studio 2019 (free edition).  I cannot find anything to add under References->Add References->Assemblies.

The documentation for ClipboardContentOptions states that the dll is Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.dll so I search for the dll and find versions in

C:\Windows\System32 (799Kb)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (566Kb),

I attempt to add these dlls via References->AddReference->Browse and in both cases get the error

`A Reference to <path to dll> could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component`

What's going on here and how do I add a Reference to this namespace?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

`Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` is a WinRT API namespace. The easiest way to gain access to these namespaces is to add the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` [NuGet package](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/calling-windows-10-apis-from-a-desktop-application-just-got-easier/) as follows:

1. Open your project/solution in Visual Studio.
2. Ensure you are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1+ or .NET Core 3.0+ per NuGet package requirements.
3. Convert any old package.config references in your project to the newer PackageReference format, by right-clicking the package.config reference and clicking `Migrate package.config to PackageReference`.
4. In Solution Explorer, right-click References then click Manage NuGet References.
5. Click the Browse heading then type `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` into the search box.
6. Click the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` (trusted by Microsoft) package then click the Install button on the right.

Alternatively, you can add a reference to `Windows.winmd` from the appropriate SDK folder typically located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata`.

Comment: Thanks Rafael,

Unfortunately I'm still having problems.  

First off for the benefit of others trying to add this Namespace it appears that the 'Default package management format' needs to be set to 'PackageReference' (in Tools->NuGet Package Manager Settings).

Comment: Having done that your solution works as described for a newly created C# Form project.  However the project I'm trying to modify was created years ago in an early version of VS and has been updated through several iterations and in now using VS 2019.

Comment: When adding the namespace using NuGet, this project reports success when installing the packages but reports an error (Missing assembly reference) during compilation.  

It seems that something's wrong with my project settings.  Does anyone have any suggestions on where I should look?

Comment: I had my target .NET Framework set to 4.5.  It's now set to 4.7.2 and working fine.

Comment: @user3495258 Great, will edit the answer with your feedback.

Comment: @user3495258 Before you go, please upvote and/or accept the answer, it would help the community. Thanks!

Comment: Saved my day in getting IAPWrapper to update for the latest SDK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For targeting Windows 10 (version 1809?) and greater using .Net 6 and greater, there is no need to add the reference. In a new WPF project created using Visual Studio 2022 if I have *Supported OS Version* set to `10.0.17763.0` or higher then I can use a class in `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` and if there is not a `using` for the namespace then the `using` is created. I assume that applies for all of `Windows.ApplicationModel`.