# Is there a way to use that UWP's Windows namespace from Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uwp, .net-7.0

I'm using VS2022, .NET7.0.

I'm trying to implement a function that automatically connects the SerialPort using USB's vid and pid.

I found that it was easier to implement by refering to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.getdeviceselectorfromusbvidpid?view=winrt-22621) rather than [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/349002/Select-a-USB-Serial-Device-via-its-VID-PID).

But, I can't use the `Windows` namespace in `Winform`.

I tried the `Nuget\Install-Package Windows` using PM, but it failed.

I add the `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` in `.csproj` of project and looked at the References Manager, but it hasn't changed.

Tried reinstalling Windows SDK 10, same thing.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try installing Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584094/17413993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a .NET 7, you do not need the NugetPackage, you need to edit the properties of the Project, and set the Target OS to 10.0.17763.0 or above. You can also modify the project file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: you're right. It actually doesn't compile and I've been looking for a solution for the past hour.

Comment: The NuGet package is for .NET 4.8.

Comment: .NET 5, 6, and 7 use the TargetFramework solution. .NET 4.X, uses the NuGet package. You can take a look at the example here [MediaCapture API in WPF or Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74949797/3110834) or download code from repository.

Answer (score 1):

<s>As per **@radian**'s comment, I solved it like this:</s>

Opened *NuGet Package Management* and installed `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts`.

I can now add `Windows` namespace normally.

---

#### EDIT

When I do the above method, there is a problem that it does not compile.

To fix this, you need to act on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028532/netsdk1135supportedosplatformversion-10-0-19041-0-cannot-be-higher-than-targetp) or the accepted answer.